# exporting MYSQL fectched row into csv in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Following is a part of my php program which is written to fetch rows from mysql table from input IDs. But I wanted to get the result directly to '.csv' file. I know php has built in function for that, but I could not include it effectively. So can anyone give a direction for export to csv using advanced php function?

```
$file = fopen("fetched.csv","w");

for($i=0;$i<=$len;$i++)
{

$lo =  $locus[$i];
mysqli_select_db($conn,"microarray");
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM anatomy WHERE locus_id = "$lo"");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query))

    {
    }  
}
```

Comment: You mean like [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/fputcsv)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query mysql and export data as CSV in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391528/query-mysql-and-export-data-as-csv-in-php)

Comment: Please refer below link

[MYSQL TO CSV][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073077/export-mysql-list-of-tables-from-mysql-to-csv-file-using-php

Comment: You have a syntax error in your query: Remove teh two double quotes at the and `$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM anatomy WHERE locus_id = ".$lo);`

Comment: Ok, I will check the link..

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need an "advanced php function". A csv file is just a sequence of comma separated columns. Try this out.

```
function addRowToCsv(& $csvString, $cols) {
    $csvString = implode(',', $cols) . PHP_EOL;
}

$csvString = '';
$first = true;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if ($first === true) {
        $first = false;
        addRowToCsv($csvString, array_keys($row));
    }
    addRowToCsv($csvString, $row);
}

header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=MyCsvFile.csv');

echo $csvString;
```

Notice that the first argument to addRowToCsv is passed by reference. This is not required and you could easily use a return value, but this is just how I would do it.

-- Edit --
I just noticed you are saving the output to a file rather than serving it as a download. If that is what you want to do then use the above but replace

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=MyCsvFile.csv');

echo $csvString;
```

With..

```
file_put_contents('MyCsvFile.csv', $csvString);
```