# Export table data to CSV with PHP, Zend

Tags: php, html, mysql, zend-framework

I have MySql data base and web site, in the web i show database values in table. I made that CSV exports the specify database model(table).

```
  `$this->view->table = $model->info('name');

    $is_csv = $this->_getParam('csv');

    if ($this->_request->isPost() && $is_csv) {

        $file1 = 'Baudų sąrašas '.$date_from.' iki '.$date_to.'.csv';
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
        if ($date_from) {
            $select->where("date >= ?", $date_from . ' 00:00:00');
        }
        if ($date_to) {
            $select->where("date <= ?", $date_to . ' 23:59:59');
        }
            $data = $model->fetchAll($select);
        foreach ($data as $fields) {

            fputcsv($fp, $fields->toArray());
        }

        fclose($fp);

        if ($file1 !== false) {

            header('Content-type: text/plain');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file1 . '"');
            exit;
        }
    }`
```

And the HTML that calls it:

```
       form method="post">
            <div class="control-group pull-right">

            <input type="hidden" name="table" value="<?php echo $this->table ?>" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn" name="csv" value="csv"><?php echo Core_Locale::translate('CSV')?></button>
                </div>
        </form>
```

Now i want to take not from data base, but from function wich has Join's to the database, but when i use
    `return $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);` it gives error non object and when i write    `return $this->fetchAll($select);` it gives me as data base data as from function...
    Do any may have some clue how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer for your question, but why don't you try this..

```
SELECT * FROM my_table INTO OUTFILE 'my_table.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Copied From : [export mysql list of tables from mysql to csv file using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073077/export-mysql-list-of-tables-from-mysql-to-csv-file-using-php)